# getColumnIndex for a column in Room of Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I was looking to get the column index from Room database in Android. Since there is no Cursor [getColumnIndex()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)), I could not find a way to get the value.

Is there any way to get something like that?

Comment: post your entity class and dao class

Comment: Return `Cursor` from select query.

Comment: Thanks @ρяσѕρєяK. Is there any way to get the cursor if I use Observable<T>?

Answer (score 1):

> I was looking to get the column index from Room database in Android

Return `Cursor` instead of custom Entity object from Dao select query like:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM DummyTable")
    LiveData<Cursor> getAllDataFromDummyTable();
    ....
    getAllDataFromDummyTable().observe(this, new Observer<Cursor>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Cursor cursor) {
               // use getColumnIndex here  
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for something like Observable<SomeModel> .

Comment: I am actually trying to track which column has been edited. The plan was to keep a string/number to indicate a column has been edited or not.